# Title bar does not scale

Tags: install4j, exe4j

(OS: Windows 10)

I created an EXE file using this config.exe4j file with exe4j.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exe4j version="9.0" transformSequenceNumber="3">
  <directoryPresets config="C:/git/Exe4jUiTest/build/libs" />
  <application name="Exe4j UI Test" distributionSourceDir="C:/dist/Exe4jUiTest" />
  <executable name="Exe4j UI Test" wrapperType="embed" executableMode="gui" checkConsoleParameter="true" dpiAware="true" />
  <java mainClass="org.example.Main" vmParameters="--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.windows=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED           --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.geom=ALL-UNNAMED           -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true" minVersion="17" maxVersion="17">
    <classPath>
      <archive location="C:/git/Exe4jUiTest/build/libs/Exe4jUiTest-0.0.1.jar" failOnError="false" />
    </classPath>
  </java>
</exe4j>
```

The title bar of this application is not adjusted to the scaling of the screen. E.g. if the application window is moved to a screen with 200% scaling...

If the application is ran using the javaw -jar command with the JAR file used in the configuration, the title bar is scaled.

[image: screenshot]
The screenshot demonstrates this issue using the HelloGui demo of Exe4j application.
The screenshot was taken on a monitor set to 225% scaling.

Leaving the scaling to the operatating system fixes the issue with the title bar.
But instead the text of the application is blurred.